# Setup babel plugin with Rails 5 webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup the `idx` babel plugin from Facebook in a Rails app that uses Webpacker.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/idx

https://github.com/rails/webpacker

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured this out. Must add it to the babel.js loader.

```
// config/webpack/loaders/babel.js

module.exports = {
  test: /\.js(\.erb)?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    plugins: [
      require('babel-plugin-idx'),
    ],
    presets: [
      ['env', { modules: false }]
    ]
  }
}
```